# JavaScript: shorthand for conditionally adding something to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a Mocha test for a server at work.

I get two potential phone numbers for a customer, at least one of which will be defined.

```
    var homePhone = result.homePhone;
    var altPhone = result.altPhone;
```

I want to use underscore's _.sample function to pick one of these at random. However, one of them may be undefined.

So what I was thinking was something like:

//pseudocode

```
var phone = _.sample([homephone || (doNothing), altphone || (doNothing)]);
```

the _.sample function looks like this:
http://underscorejs.org/#sample

the problem of course, is there is no shorthand syntax that I know of to conditionally add something to an array.

The verbose way to do what I want is:

```
var phoneArray = [];

if(homePhone){
 phoneArray.push(homePhone);
}
if(altPhone){
 phoneArray.push(homePhone);
}

var phoneSelection = _.sample(phoneArray);
```

is there a more elegant way to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: The verbose way is a good way. You could 'add a sentinel value' and filter it later, but why.. bother.

Comment: yeah but what if you had 3 4, 5, 6, 7 or 8 ...or 20...phone numbers? :) think about it

Comment: Then I would use an array - or discreet object, or other method of knowing fields - for the different phone numbers and iteration. *The "verbose method" does not imply code duplication.* Also, if starting with such a sequence, the various map/filter operations are intrinsically more useful from the start; however, as presented I stand by my original comment.

Comment: I don't think tests should be random.

Comment: @TMB for the tests there is a new set of data coming down the pipeline. Let's say 1000 pieces of data. So we just pick a random subset of the data because we can't test of all of it. Makes sense right? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using underscore, I would suggest leveraging `compact`:

```
var phone = _.sample(_.compact([homephone, altphone]));
```

This is basically a shortened version of dave's answer, since `compact` is literally implemented as `function(array) { return _.filter(array, _.identity); }`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `.filter`:

```
_.sample([homephone, altphone].filter(_.identity))
```

Another way would be:

```
_.sample([homephone, altphone]) || homephone || altphone;
```

Comment: so the filter will only return defined values in the case? that is !== undefined and !== null?

Comment: `_.sample([homephone, altphone].filter(_.identity))` to make it even simpler.

Comment: @DavidThomas you don't need that because in the end I just want one phone number which _.sample with one argument will give me.

Comment: I thought _.identify was a function, is the syntax for the first example correct? and if so why?

Comment: `_.identity` is a function, but because we use it without the `()` it does not get evaluated immediately, but is used as if it were an anonymous function.  The source code for it is (probably) `_.identity = function(i) { return i; }`, so it functions exactly as if we had done `_.sample([homephone, altphone].filter(function(i) {return i; }))`

Comment: I see, but somehow the filter function combined with the identify function is only returning values that are not null?

Comment: Right, the filter function will go through each item, and if it returns a "truthy" value it will be included in the returned array.  Since we just have each element return itself, anything that is not truthy (0, "", null, undefined) will not be included

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
  var phone = (homephone && altphone)? _.sample([homephone, altphone]) : (homephone || altphone);
```

Comment: this would work for two phone numbers, but I was looking for a generic solution that might work for 3,4,10,20 etc.

Answer (score 2):

Array literals in JavaScript:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

...are a way to *statically* declare which things go in which positions in an array. In other words, when you write the code, you already know where things will go.

In your scenario, the positions are only known dynamically. In other words, you don't know where they'll go until you run the program on a given set of inputs.

So basically what you're asking for is impossible, barring any radical changes to how array literals work in future versions of JS. However, if all you want is to save typing, @dave's answer is pretty nice. I'm mainly just clarifying that array literals by themselves don't have this capability.